# About changing attributes of draggable elements

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change the attributes of a draggable element during dragging (font color, background color, z-index).  I don't know if the problem is IE9, but there are attributes for which the code works, there are others for which it doesn't.

```
$(function() {
    $('.comurl').draggable({ 
        start: function(event, ui) { 
            $(this).css("background-color","red"); //works
            $(this).css("color","red");            //doesn't
            $(this).css("z-index","999999");       //doesn't
            },
        stop: function(event, ui) {  
            $(this).css("background-color","green"); //works
            $(this).css("color","green");            //doesn't
            $(this).css("z-index","auto");           //doesn't
        } 
    });
});
```

Are the names for the properties different when called in that way?  Is this a problem with IE9?

Comment: Interesting... could you [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) a demo?

Comment: how about `$(this).css({"background-color":"red","color":"red","z-index":"999999"});` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not use a class instead?

```
$(function() {
    $('.comurl').draggable({ 
        start: function(event, ui) { 
            $(this).addClass('dragging');
            },
        stop: function(event, ui) {  
            $(this).removeClass('dragging');
        } 
    });
});
```

note: there's a default class (`ui-draggable-dragging`) that you could use in your css without having to write any additional js as well.

Comment: There is, it is called `ui-draggable-dragging`.

Comment: Also +1d your answer, I don't know why the OP's code does not work, but CSS definitions don't belong in your jQuery code. It easily and quickly becomes unmaintainable. Using a class is a much better practice.

Comment: @DavidWick Yes, a class works better.  Now the only problem is the z-index.  Seems that with .addClass and .removeClass the z-index is changed.  But the draggable is still confined to the container div.  When I try to drag it it disappears under the borders of that container.  I want to drag the draggable element to another container div.  This doesn't happen if I set a fixed z-index for the draggable in the CSS styles.  But that approach results in a weird looking page with the draggables divs floating on top of other elements.

Comment: Using a class to set the attributes works.  Had another problem where if there is overflow:hidden the draggables do not go beyond the container.  Had to remove overflow: hidden.